# Синхронизация времени при помощи python с pool.ntp.org

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь синхронизировать время при помощи python.

```
import ntplib
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = t.request('ru.pool.ntp.org')
response.offset
os.system('date ' + time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(response.tx_time)))
```

в ответ получаю открытый cmd с ответом - "Указана недопустимая дата. Введите новую дату:"

Comment: Читали документацию к команде date? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date

Comment: Прочитал. Изменил на ...('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'...). Ошибка исчезла, но время и дата так и не меняются...